# NVARCHAR data not transfering - SSIS 2008R2

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, nvarchar

I am having troubles where a data flow task is completing and the table is being loaded but all of the character fields are empty. The sad thing is all run perfectly during development and testing.  But there are environment differences between dev and prod, dev is fully 32 bit and prod was just set up and is 64 bit.

So the scenario is I built the system on an XP machine using 32 bit SSIS with a SQL Server 2000 back end (I'm working for a not for profit at the moment, it was all they had). The source is a firebird data base. I have deployed to prod and that is where all of the date and number data is transferred just not the character data.

Prod is running Windows 2008 64 bit to SQL Server 2008 R2 64 bit. We installed the 32 bit Firebird ODB driver, set up the firebird service and they are all working fine. In the debug menu I have set Run 64 bit runtime to false. I checked all of the advanced edit items under both the source and destination tasks and there appears to me to be no problems there, `DT_WSTR` and `NVARCHAR`. I've done a preview in both source and destination and in the source the missing data is all displaying fine. All I changed between the prod and the dev environments are the connection configurations, by hand by opening them up and changing the ODBC source for the source and the SQL Server for the dest. I took the Dev data base off line to make sure there were not problems related to poor connection config changes.  So running in debug mode there is a row being created in SQL for each row in firebird, but only the number and date fields are being populated, the character (all `nvarchar` to match firebird) are failing to populated.

Where have I missed something, this is my first 32 bit to 64 bit conversion and I don't know if it was as simple as building the manifest and then deploying the package after changing it's connection configs and deploying to `MSDB`.

Thanks for any help.
Mark

Comment: You should first rule out that there might be info in your target field, but your client app is unable to display it. Run `SELECT YourNVarcharField, ASCII(YourNVarcharField) A, LEN(YourNVarcharField) L,  FROM YourTable`. Do you get any values in the A or L field? If so there are values in your field, you just can't see them.

Comment: Also what happens if you use SSIS to dump a few of these tables to text files instead of a database - do you see text?

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  So I ran the SQL against the destination table and all of them are 0 length and null ASCII.  I then set up a little data task to copy the data from the table I have been running my tests against to a flat file and the flat file is performing the same, no data in the Unicode fields, only the date and numeric.

Comment: and if you connect to this firebird database with some kind of native tool (i.e. a firebird querying tool, or whatever app is sued to add data to it), you can definitely see textual data? It just pays to check so you can narrow down exactly where the issue is.

Comment: I've connected using the front end application and the data displays.  Also in the preview window for the source connection via SSIS all of the data is displaying correctly.  It is just as the data transfers out of firebird that I lose any character columns, and they are all Unicode.

Comment: Also ,go into the data flow, right click in the source, press "Show Advanced Editor", go to the "Input and Output Properties" tab, open out OLE DB Source Output (or whatever the non-error one is), Open "External Columns" and click on one of your troublesome columns - what is the codepage, Datatype and length? Repeat for "Output Columns". "External Columns" shows the datatype reported by the ODBC driver. "Output Columns" shows the datatype used internally by SSIS. Also, you're not getting any truncation errors are you?

Comment: Sorry I see you've already done that....

Comment: Thanks ElectricLlama,

Comment: Ooops, So all data source match on type and length and I get no errors when executing in debug mode, just an empty set of destination columns.  Given the source connection is working there must be something happening during the data pump to the destination.  What else can I look at?

Comment: See my answer just below, although it doesn't make any sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poking around I found this

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1254262-364-2.aspx

(which I was involved in - I'm the can of beans)

Which says to change the redirect property of the column to redirect row, then pick it up again and merge it back in.

Which makes absolutely no sense, but apperently worked for at least two people.

Perhaps if this fixes the issue you could provide a more detailed analysis of how it fixes it.

Comment: PS Even though it mentions informix, I saw the resolution elsewhere on the web for Firebird.

Comment: I'm curious.... the fix implies that whole rows were failing - after implementing this fix do the success and failure row counts change reconcile to the original row count?

Comment: OK all I needed to change was the error flow for one of the columns and then all functions fine.  No records are errored and the total loaded matches the totals from the source.  This is very very strange behaviour.  I guess it is time to upgrade.